# How to find the length of starting 3 charachter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to find the length of starting 3 characters in python, here is the sample of what i am trying.

```
def front3(str):
  front = str[:3]
  if len (front) < 3:
    return str
```

Comment: wouldnt the length of the starting 3 characters always be 3?

Comment: no, if the string itself is shorter than 3. but yet it's overcomplicated... `len(s) < 3` is enough, no need for slicing...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if the string is less than 3 characters he would get an `IndexError`?

Comment: no: `>>> "e"[:3] =>
'e'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def front3(str):
       if len(str)>3:
            return 3
       else:
            return len(str)
```